# Issue with Mathf.Clamp, MovePosition & GetKeyDown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently started coding using Unity and I´ve been stumped on an issue.

I´ve tried using `Vector3`, but get the following error: `cannot convert from void to float`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FrogController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.up);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.up * -1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.right * -1);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.right);
        }
    }
}
```

I´d like to use `Mathf.Clamp` to limit the side to side and up and down movement of the `transform.rigidbody`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll make it easier on everyone if you include the entire error message (including any error code(s)) and give an indication of where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like with Vector3.Max and Vector3.Min?

```
public Vector3 Max;
public Vector3 Min;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {  
        Vector3 desiredPosition;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            desiredPosition = transform.position + transform.up;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            desiredPosition = transform.position + transform.up * -1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            desiredPosition = transform.position + transform.right * -1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            desiredPosition = transform.position + transform.right;
        }

        desiredPosition = Vector3.Min(desiredPosition, this.Max);
        desiredPosition = Vector3.Max(desiredPosition, this.Min);

        rb.MovePosition(desiredPosition);   
    }
```

In this example, be sure to set Min and Max in the inspector.

Notice that we pass Max to the Min function and Min to the Max function.  This is because Vector3.Min returns the smaller components of the two vectors you pass into it.  When your position is beyond the maximum, we want to return the position because it is the smaller of the two.  When position is less than maximum, we want position instead (again, the smaller of the two).  The reverse is true for Vector3.Max.

Comment: Hi, the code worked! Do you mind commenting on why you wrote it this way instead of using Mathf.Clamp???

Comment: Just personal preference.  I chose them because I like to do vector operations on vectors. You could replace Vector3.Min and Vector3.Max with some code like `desiredPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(desiredPosition.x, Min.x, Max.x)`and it would be just as good